# SSRS Setting Target report path using Configuration Manager

Tags: ssrs-2017

Using 2017

I have several reports in a single project that need to be deployed in different folders (e.g Central/Sales, Central/Marketing)

I setup multiple configurations, I select a config for the project (e.g. Central-Sales) and change the TargetReportFolder to Central/Sales,  but then when I switch back to Central/Marketing, it has changed the TargetreportFolder there too.

How do I save the setting for each config

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Please to check out this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/set-deployment-properties-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15#to-set-configuration-manager-properties

Answer (score 0):

I would create one project per deployment setting within your main solution. Then you can move each of your reports to the corresponding project and you can deploy to your different destinations via the project.